# WARNING in ./src/main.js 6:8-15 "export 'default' (imported as 'vuefire') was not found in 'vuefire'

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I don't know why he can't find his way

`main.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import 'firebase'
import vuefire from 'vuefire';
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
vue.use(vuefire)

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

> WARNING in ./src/main.js
>       6:8-15 "export 'default' (imported as 'vuefire') was not found in 'vuefire'
>        @ ./src/main.js
>        @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server`
>       ./src/main.js

pls help me

Comment: You need to look at how you're exporting vuefire. You're trying to import a named export by the looks of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/tree/master/packages/vuefire), I think you want the import line for vuefire to be this, as the vuefire package doesn't have a default export:

```
import { firestorePlugin } from 'vuefire';
```

(Alternatively you might need `rtdbPlugin` instead of `firestorePlugin` if you are using the realtime database and not firestore, more [here](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/getting-started.html#installation))

And when you actually call `Vue.use` it should look like this:

```
Vue.use(firestorePlugin);
```

Comment: tnx <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3